# Changing button appearance in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, drop-down-menu

So I've got a standard dropdown menu in my HTML. I've also got the background colored, and I have a background image that I want to use as a button.

But there's a problem, because I can't get the default button to disappear in Firefox. Even though I can get the button to disappear in Webkit using -webkit-appearance:none; I can't get it to go away in Firefox.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/wG7UB/

And I'd prefer not to revert to a heavily styled unordered list if at all possible. Thanks!

Comment: Looks the same in IE as in FireFox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I go answering my own question... I just wrapped my select tag with a div, and used a pseudo element to cover up the button. Slightly hackish, and I don't like using the pointless div, but I guess it works okay. Then I set the CSS of the pseudo element to `pointer-events:none;` so that it would allow clicks through the image.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/howlermiller/nchUt/1/

Answer (score 0):

What do you exactly want to do?I'm not sure i understand fully what exactly you're trying to do

if you want to make it disappear then you can use "{display: none}"

or you can use "-moz-appearance" property if there is any.

Comment: I'm trying to make the standard UI button disappear, so I can replace it with my own background image. `-moz-appearance`, although it should work, doesn't, due to a bug in Firefox. So I was wondering if there was any other simple ways of doing it... Perhaps not though.

Comment: if possible then please use jquery drop down menu instead of "select"